# Use same DateTime for entire select statement

Tags: t-sql

I inherited some code that looks like this:

```
update hm
   set hm.status = '130'
      ,hm.updatedtimestr = convert(varchar,getdate(),101) + ' ' + convert(varchar,getdate(),108)
  from homemain hm
 where cast(hm.ExpireTime as DATE) < GETDATE()
   and hm.Status = '100'
;
```

This has the classic problem of calling a time routine multiple times in a single routine that if the clock ticks from just before midnight to just after midnight between `GETDATE()` calls undesirable things will happen in the code.  Specifically, `updatetimestr` could be set to 24 hours prior to the actual time.

I can add a

```
declare @mynow datetime;
set @mynow = GETDATE()
```

and use `@mynow` instead of `GETDATE()`, but I would rather use something built into tsql that is defined as returning the same time for the entire execution.

Is there a variation of `GETDATE()` that will return the same time for the entire execution of the statement?  Perhaps statement start time?

Please ignore that the previous developer storing a datetime in a string; it is not my doing and I am systematically refactoring that kind of crud out of the system.

Comment: The solution is exactly as you presented = using variable ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `FORMAT` (starting with 2012):

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss')
```

Comment: This is a good answer for this particular case the real case has several more GETDATE()s that can not be combined.